# How to take user characteristics into account while building a recommendation system?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I'm learning Recommender systems. I have user's age, profession, gender etc. available in the dataset, along with their interaction scores with the available videos. I also have certain characteristics about each video like genre, #views etc. I am thinking of applying collaborative filtering for this particular dataset, but most examples online ignore this information whereas these characteristics can help understand why a certain user rated a certain video with the rating he gave, and can help produce more accurate predictions. Are there some algorithms which take this information into account?